# Radio button selection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<form action="search_result.php">


    <table align="Left" width="98%" border="0">


        <tr>
            <td><h3><u><center><font color="#C71002">Search Blood</font></center></u></h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="Left">
                <b>Select Blood Group</b> <br/>
                <select name="b">
                    <option value="A+">A+</option>
                    <option value="A-">A-</option>
                    <option value="B+">B+</option>
                    <option value="B-">B-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td>

                <div align="left">
                    <b>Search By</b>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function () {
            if ($("#ins").is(":checked")) {
                $("#institute").show();
                $("#area").hide();
            } else {
                $("#institute").hide();
                $("#area").show();
            }
        });
    });
                </script>

                <input type="radio" id="ins" name="chkPassPort" />
                <label for="ins">
                    Institute
                </label>

                <input type="radio" id="arearadio" name="chkPassPort" />
                <label for="arearadio">
                    Area
                </label>

                <div id="institute" style="display: none">
                    <input type="text" name="institute" placeholder="Type an institute name" required >


                </div>
                <div id="area" style="display: none">

                    <?php
                    include 'area.php';
                    ?>


                </div>

            </td>                                                                                                                                                                    
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
</form>
```

When I select first radio button, it works (submit button), but when I select second radio button 'submit button' doesn't work. I tried by putting the submit button within the div. But the result is same.Why? I can't understand.

area.php contains three selection boxes.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/efu5e6p7/

Comment: selection is working but submit button doesn't work

Comment: As in, it isn't submitting the form? Or that it doesn't show the submit button?

Comment: Selection is working for me. But my problem is - when i select the second button submit button doesn't work. but first selection is working fine.

Comment: Javascript console gives me this error `An invalid form control with name='institute' is not focusable.`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<form action="search_result.php" novalidate>
```

Comment: if its working . can you confirm my answer? :) 
thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

When `Jquery` code is getting parsed, the compiler does not recognize element `checkpassport`. This is because we are referring to the element even before declaring it. Move your `Jquery` code after the radio button. Its good practice to keep the Jquery code after the HTML.

```
<form action="search_result.php">
        <table align="Left" width="98%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><h3><u><center><font color="#C71002">Search Blood</font></center></u></h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="Left">
                    <b>Select Blood Group</b> <br/>
                    <select name="b">
                        <option value="A+">A+</option>
                        <option value="A-">A-</option>
                        <option value="B+">B+</option>
                        <option value="B-">B-</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>        
                    <div align="left">
                        <b>Search By</b>
                    </div>   
                    <input type="radio" id="ins" name="chkPassPort" />
                    <label for="ins">
                        Institute
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" id="arearadio" name="chkPassPort" />
                    <label for="arearadio">
                        Area
                    </label>
                    <div id="institute" style="display: none">
                        <input type="text" name="institute" placeholder="Type an institute name" required >
                    </div>
                    <div id="area" style="display: none">
                        <?php
                        include 'area.php';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </td>                                                                                                                                                                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function () {
                if ($("#ins").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#institute").show();
                    $("#area").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#institute").hide();
                    $("#area").show();
                }
              return false;
            });
        });
                    </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: i guess you will have to add `novalidate` in the form tag as suggested by @ar em